# How to process a UDP dns request

Tags: java, networking, dns, udp

I was working on a simple DNS server. I preferred doing this on my own since its a learning experience too. However, am stuck trying to understand DNS requests. The issue is, the data (as a String) appears with some extra unreadable characters which I donot know how to process. I was even expecting something like 'WhoIs google.com response code 1234'but rather got what you see on the screenshot
[caption after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ID5A.png)
And my source code..

```
package com.donsoft.ambient;

import java.net.*;

public class Dns {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(53);
            //Now for reading the packets
            while(true){
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; //I think that size is good
                DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                sock.receive(in);
                String data = new String(in.getData());
                if(data!=null){
                    process(in);
                }
                Thread.sleep(200); //To reduce CPU usage
            }
        }catch(Exception error){error.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void process(DatagramPacket pack){
        //I just print it out
        //But this is supposed to read the query and respond
        //Am hooked at the point of formatting the data
        String data = new String(pack.getData());
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: "am stuck trying to understand DNS requests." You will need to read RFC 1034 and 1035, multiple times, to start with. DNS is a binary protocol, not a string based one, and there is name compression. And a lot of edge cases. In short, it is not the simpler protocol to learn. If your goal is learning network programming, peek something simpler like whois indeed or RDAP even. Except if you really need to learn the DNS, in which case you first need to read some RFCs...

Comment: Also, have a look at tools like wireshark: they listen on the network and pretty print the packets, it fully understand DNS so it can show you both the binary capture and the corresponding result of parsing.

Comment: Also any programming language has a DNS library, so something you can use to build and parse DNS messages with an high level API. You should look at one for Java, both to use it to understand how it works and then reading its own source code to understand better how the DNS protocols is handled by the library.

Comment: Thanks bro, extra reading i guess. Thank u